# How do I fix Error: duplicate case value in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, char, switch-statement, operators

I'm fairly new to c++ and programming in general. I want to be able to test for the origLetter char. However, it could be 'a' or 'A'. When I attempt to execute my program it throws back an error. "Error: duplicate case values". I want to include both of the case values. How do I get around this?

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
   char origLetter;

   cin >> origLetter;

   switch (origLetter) {
   case 'A'||'a':
      cout << "Alpha" << endl;
      break;
   case 'b'||'B':
      cout << "Beta" << endl;
      break;
   default:
      cout << "Unknown" << endl;
      break;
   }
```

Comment: 1) `case 'A'||'a':` -> `case 'A': case 'a':` The same for other `case`s. 2) "_I'm fairly new to c++ and programming in general._" You won't go far in C++, by coding randomly. Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
switch (origLetter) {
   case 'A':
   case 'a':
      cout << "Alpha" << endl;
      break;
   case 'b':
   case 'B':
      cout << "Beta" << endl;
      break;
   default:
      cout << "Unknown" << endl;
      break;
   }
```